# Индивидуальный стиль для каждой ссылки

Tags: html, css, javascript

Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении на эти ссылки каждая из ссылок имела свой собственный фон заливки background-color без написания персональных стилей каждой ссылки?

```
<nav>
    <a href="#" class="a">Photo</a>
    <a href="#" class="a">Video</a>
    <a href="#" class="a">Press</a>
    <a href="#" class="a">Staff</a>
    <a href="#" class="a">Alumnus</a>
    <a href="#" class="a">Contact Us</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без написания персональных стилей для каждой ссылки не обойтись, конечно можно яваскриптом навешать индекс или просто в цикле на каждый отдельный элемент повесить отдельно события на хувер с изменением стиля, но зачем лишний яваскрипт. Можно навешать стили каждой отдельной ссылке не навешивая на нее новый класс:

```
nav a {background:red}
nav a +a{background:green}
nav a +a +a{background:blue}
nav a +a +a +a{background:yellow}
nav a +a +a +a +a{background:orange}
nav a +a +a +a +a +a{background:black}
```

Работает в ие7 (в ие6 не смотрел)

Answer (score 2):

1. Псевдоклассы [:nth-child](http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child). (Чистый CSS.)
2. jQuery. Проверять индекс [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
3. Закрасить изначально им фон каким-то (прямо инлайн через style=""), но указать в качестве бэкграунд-имидж файл с цветом фона страницы. В CSS указать: `a:hover{background-image: none}`, тогда рисунок будет пропадать, обнажая фон.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [onmouseover](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp) хотя все же с CSS будет эстетичнее так сказать.

Answer (score 0):

```
     <nav>
       < a href="#" style="color:#FF0000;text-decoration:none">Photo</a>
       <a href="#" style="color:#FF0000;text-decoration:none">Video</a>
       < a href="#" style="color:#FF0000;text-decoration:none">Press</a>
       < a href="#" style="color:#FF0000;text-decoration:none">Staff</a>
       < a href="#" style="color:#FF0000;text-decoration:none">Alumnus</a>
       < a href="#" style="color:#FF0000;text-decoration:none">Contact  Us</a>
</nav>
```

По умолчанию цвет ссылки поставил #FF0000, меняйте его по своему усмотрению )))

P.S. лишние пробелы уберите

Comment: Вот вы и попались со своими стилями на элементах (только что писал коммент на ваш ответ в каком-то вопросе), если ссылкам указать style="color:#ff0000", то хувер теперь не сработает и они будут всегда указанного цвета, а вопрос был про цвет именно при наведении на ссылку.

Comment: а что мешает добавить цвет для выделенной и неактивной ссылки?